# asp.net mvc html Drop down list helper isn't selecting option

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

In my controller I generated a SelectList that I pass to the dropdown helper:

```
  <%= Html.DropDownList("abc123", Model.SomeList) %>
```

I look at the querystring for a value, which is a ID.

I then loop through all the items in the SelectList and if it is equal to the ID, I do:

```
item.Selected = true;
```

The controller action then passes this SelectList to the view and then to the Html helper.

In debug mode I can see the value does get set to true, but the html renders without selecting the item.

What can the issue be?

Comment: In the view, temporarily comment out the dropdownlist, loop through Model.SomeList and confirm that the right item is "selected".

Comment: Could you show the controller action that performs the steps you described in your post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you are doing wrong as you've shown 0 code but this definitely works:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
    var model = new SelectList(new[]
    {
        new { Id = 1, Name = "item 1" },
        new { Id = 2, Name = "item 2" },
    }, "Id", "Name", id);
    return View(model);
}
```

and in your view:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<SelectList>" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <%= Html.DropDownList("abc123", Model) %>

</asp:Content>
```

Now if you navigate to `/home/index/1` the first item is selected, if you navigate to `/home/index/2` the second item item selected.

Also if you are using ASP.NET MVC 2.0 I would recommend you the strongly typed [`DropDownListFor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor.aspx) helper instead of [`DropDownList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist.aspx).

Comment: thanks it works when you pass the selectedValue in the constructor of selectList.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a common MVC problem:

[Html.DropDownListFor not behaving as expected ASP.net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046811/html-dropdownlistfor-not-behaving-as-expected-asp-net-mvc)